# When is the new site design being launched?

Tags: discussion, design, graduation

The new Worldbuilding site design (which looks awesome) was being discussed and demonstrated [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2916/worldbuilding-site-design?lq=1). Does anyone have any official (or accurate) information as to how long we have to wait before the new design is implemented?

Comment: Not at the moment no.

Comment: We're trying to get hold of some, but no news yet

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Today.

I apologize for the delay. We're really excited to update the design and launch the site. A few things came up at work and outside of work that put us behind schedule. I will make sure that we carve out some time to move this forward next week.

Comment: Thanks for the update Kurtis

Comment: Wooohoooooo :) Thanks, guys!