# Worldbuilding Site Design Updates: March 15

Tags: discussion, design

Thank you for [all of your feedback](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2916/worldbuilding-site-design) and patience while we made design updates. Below are a list of updates and planned updates.

**Logo**

Based on the community's discussion, we've made some adjustments to the logo:

- we [added a halo](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2917/13448),
- saturated the colors a bit more,
- and made the [world a bit larger](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2928/13448) than the surrounding text.

[image: Worldbuilding logo]

**Multiverse**

We decided to mix up the two themes a little bit by creating a variation of the main characters for the meta theme and having a more gothic, steam-punk-inspired city in the main theme and using the futuristic city on Meta.

[image: Worldbuilding posters]
[Click to view larger version.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPQbO.jpg)

**Swag**

Based on some of the comments, we decided to go with the artwork for the [Tshirt](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2916/worldbuilding-site-design#comment7960_2916) and make one of the items a [sketchbook](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2916/worldbuilding-site-design#comment7970_2916).

[image: Worldbuilding branded sketchbook and t-shirt]

**Site Design**

The following updates are being made to the site design, and we'll share those when the site is live:

- added contrast to the tags,
- [toned down the background color](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2923/13448) a little bit,
- added a hint of greenish color to the right-hand side to balance out the figures on the left,
- and adjusted shadows on the figures.

Comment: So .. what's that pile of _stuff_ to the left of the characters?

Comment: Very nice!  Thanks for the update.  I love how you've handled meta as "like, but not like" main.

Comment: Overall I like it. I think the logo/title thing is perfect now with the ringed planet etc. I think the t-shirt could do with having the worldbuilding title added.

Comment: I see you slipped in a little something extra for us, too.  Nice touch! :-)

Comment: Does anyone know when the new site design will be launched?

Comment: @Andre They definitely need to change that conspicuously shaped structure there, I agree

Comment: The balloon-whale! I did not see it the first time! Nice touch. Was that what you meant, Monica?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin yes, that's what I was referring to.

Comment: Looks great! Thanks

Comment: @AndreiROM maybe its mossy rocks? Or some sort of cactus like vegetation?

Comment: @AndreiROM I assumed cactus (like overactor suggested), based on the desert-like expanse of land.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - regardless of whether it's a cactus or a weird growth of another kind it still looks kinda gross. That being said, I love _everything else_ about the design

Comment: This is *awesome*! I'm going to be looking out for a chance to get that T-shirt, and the sketchbook along with it.

Comment: When am I able to buy the shirt, I need to be dripping in swagoo

Comment: Why not stick the planet in the logo in the swag background?

Comment: oh dear that's nice; need shirt and book asap

Comment: So any news on this?

Comment: It seems the inmates are getting restless. [Any news on the progress of the new site design?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3487/29)

Comment: I really like it!

Comment: Hmm, so just curious... any update on when the swag will be available? Somehow I missed this post before, but that stuff looks great!