# Any news on the progress of the new site design?

Tags: discussion, design

The latest information we've had on the [site design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/worldbuilding-site-design-updates-march-15?cb=1) was about a month ago. Does anyone have any information as to what progress is being made as well as when we could expect to see the site design in action?

Comment: It will be launched soon.

Comment: Actually soon, or Soon™?

Comment: @Pyritie - the fact that it's been a week is an answer in and of itself :P

Comment: 6 to 8 random units of time.

Comment: @AndreiROM it's been a month now :P

Comment: @fi12 - I remembered this comment, and wanted to find it again and comment on it, but was too lazy to look for it. You read my mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## March 4.

It's been done..