# can we make a skin or theme for the site?

Tags: feature-request, design

sorry newbie here, probably stupid question but I couldn't find an answer searching the site

I see other stack communities have a themed page and a logo, while we have the default one.

Can we also have one?

Comment: Have a look at this Post to know when there are news: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3487/any-news-on-the-progress-of-the-new-site-design

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get out of Beta (which Worldbuilding is) and it requires StackExchange to make a site theme for you....which they are in the process of doing for us.

So, Yes and it's coming.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

They've already designed [one](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/worldbuilding-site-design-updates-march-15?lq=1). They're just putting on the final touches and then we'll be all set.