# Is the background image of this site some kind of easter-egg/meta-joke?

Tags: discussion, design

I didn't give too much attention to the page design when I first start to follow WB, and now that I notice it, it just got stuck in my mind.

Is the background image used in WB based to an specific story/book/movie that already exist? If this is the case, I would like to know to which one, just to know more about it.

I also noticed that some of the artwork change if you are in the meta-section:

[image]
[image]

Is there a special reason for this?

Also, I don't know if this question was already made/answered, so sorry if this is the case.

Comment: That was part of [Kurtis's multiverse idea](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3353/627).

Comment: oh thanks!, that's pretty interesting

Comment: The dress the small person on the upper image is wearing is most certainly a [Czech flag](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR7zbgJF4yJgn2LuRXfUN0aCGgAUrHuyalWzO2QJQlkQTZ9DGatzg).

Comment: It seems that the Main pace is scifi, and the Meta page is fantasy.

Answer (score 12):

Kurtis Beavers, the SE team member who created our site design, explained the background: [Worldbuilding Site Design Updates: March 15](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/worldbuilding-site-design-updates-march-15).  The idea of varying main and meta, beyond just the gray-scale transformation used on most sites, was quite intentional.

The design isn't based on a specific, pre-existing work, but after Kurtis shared the original design a Worldbuilding user, Joe Bloggs, wrote [The Lost Builder](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-lost-builder-355cf7de7ec6#.ouqk3afyg) based on it.  Kurtis just might be the first person whose SE design work has inspired fan fiction.